# How to open waze app with location Address in (Android/ios) app using xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, waze

I want show location address on the waze app from xamarin forms.While trying it is showing the navigation rather than the address.Also how can i show pin along with location address in waze app ?Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance!
Attaching waze url : https://waze.com/ul?q=66%20Acacia%20Avenue&ll=45.6906304,-120.810983&navigate=yes

refrence link https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/

Comment: SO what you want is that your application will call the Waze app to show directions1?

Comment: Have a try with `https://waze.com/ul?q=66%20Acacia%20Avenue&ll=45.6906304,-120.810983` without paramater `&navigate=yes`.Maybe the pin in the waze doesn't show much information.

Comment: This will work,But it ill show the direction navigation page.It is not showing the page with address and pin.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use below code with Address, latitude, longitude and navigate = yes

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.OpenUri(new Uri("https://waze.com/ul?q=your address&ll=latitude, longitude&navigate=yes"));
```

This code will work on both platforms. I have checked in Android.

Comment: This will work but it is showing direction navigation screen instead of Address screen.I want the address should be displayed in the screen.

Comment: can you provide the screenshot, like how you need?